# Failed to get FileOutputStream

Tags: java, android

I have a function to copy files, I tried the code and ended up with an error. after I debug, the error part is FileOutputStream, is there any solution ?

```
btn_install.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            copy = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, title + ".zip");
            paste = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/games/com.mojang/minecraftpe/");

            if (!paste.exists()) {
                paste.mkdirs();
            }

            try {
                copyDatas(copy, paste);
            }catch (IOException e){
                Log.d("error install", "becuase : " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });

private void copyDatas(File source, File target) throws IOException{
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(source);
        out = new FileOutputStream(target + title + ".zip");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int lenght;
        while ((lenght = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
            out.write(buffer, 0, lenght);
        }
    } finally {
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well which error did you get? Which exception?

Comment: `paste.mkdirs();` That should be: `if (!paste.mkdirs()){Toast(..sorry could not create directory...); return;}`

Comment: the error in the rest is null and the out is null. after i debug mode, the part out = new FileOutputStream(target + title + ".zip");  skipped. so the logcat tells variable in and out are null. (sorry for bad english)

Comment: I think your problem come from your new File(Environment.Download... and so. Doesn't make sens in android. Environment.Download is not a direct path to the download directory but just a string "Download". Since version Q, you need to access by using the mediaStore. Before Q, you need to build the full path up to Environment.Download directory. Please google it, there is thousand of subject on that.

Comment: `copy = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, title + ".zip");` That is no valid path to begin with. You can check for yourself adding code `if(!copy.exists()){ Toast(...); return;}`

Comment: @blackapps but the data can be retrieved

Comment: see my image, my in variable can retriveved data, but my out variable cant, so it's skipped and make variable in and out null [link](https://imgur.com/Y6nOYee)